# Dimension too large error with small number

Tags: tikz

I get a "Dimension too large" error because of `\tmp` but I don't understand why, because the result is not that large (around 1).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-0.10000, xscale=0.10000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]

\def\xxpl{834.5599}
\def\yxpl{-46.1934}

\def\xxpr{1567.4944}
\def\yxpr{723.6958}

\def\tmp{(\yxpr-\yxpl)/(\xxpr-\xxpl)}
\draw[black] (0,0) -- ++({10*\tmp},{-1*10});      % Works
\draw[black] (0,0) -- ++({100*\tmp},{-1*100});    % Doesn't work

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do you know why ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\def`, the expression defined is just replace in the subsequent code. Unfortunately, it looks like tikz cannot compute a complex expression such as `(\yxpr-\yxpl)/(\xxpr-\xxpl)`. You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead of `\def`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-0.10000, xscale=0.10000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]

\def\xxpl{834.5599}
\def\yxpl{-46.1934}

\def\xxpr{1567.4944}
\def\yxpr{723.6958}

\pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{(\yxpr-\yxpl)/(\xxpr-\xxpl)}

%\draw[black] (0,0) -- ++({10*\tmp},{-1*10});      % Works
\draw[black] (0,0) -- ++({100*\tmp},{-1*100});      % Now work!

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Paul, it works ! I remember `\pgfmathsetmacro` for computation and `\def` for just replace in the text.

Comment: Great! Anything you'd like me to detail before you accept the answer?

Comment: Actually I just forgot to accept your answer. Thank's for coming back and point this oversight out to me.